# What is the meaning of "[:-2]" in "header_text = f.read(header_text_size)[:-2].decode('utf-16').encode('utf-8') "

Tags: java, python, utf-8, slice

```
header_text = f.read(header_text_size)[:-2].decode('utf-16').encode('utf-8')
```

What is the meaning of `[:-2]` in this Python code? I want to translate this into Java, and I need to know what it does.

Answer (score 0):

Slice from the sequence, the first element (inclusive) to the 2nd to last (exclusive).

For example:

```
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = x[:-2]
print(y)  # [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Slices always include the "start" argument, and exclude the "stop" argument.

Also, negative indices to slices always represent counting backwards from the end.  (-1 means the last index, -2, means the second to last, etc).

[More on slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation)

Comment: Are you right the result of the "print(y)"?Why is the different result from your answer to @wookie919?

Comment: @feemung Looks like Tigerhawk caught the typo for me, sorry about that.

Comment: no matters，good luck for you .

Answer (score 0):

**a_list[:-2]** drops the last 2 elements from the list **a_list**.
**a_string[:-2]** drops the last 2 chars from the string **a_string** (probably your case):

```
>>> s = 'some string with last chars 012'
>>> s[:-2]
'some string with last chars 0'
```